# Copy Formula till data ends

Tags: vb.net, excel, copy, formula

What would be the procedure to copy formula in Excel column C till the data ends in Column B in VB.Net.
I am using this code in VB.Net which writes the formula in cell C2. [I don't have any blank cell in Column A and Column B]

```
.Range("C2").Formula = "=Sum(A2:B2)"
```

I want to copy formula till the data ends in "column C" or "Column A" from Vb.net. I know the code for VBA(Macro)

```
Range("C2").Copy Range("C3", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset (0, 1))
```

Any Suggestions on the VB.Net.....

Comment: Have you tried to use a loop until the data ends in column B? How does the data end without the cell being blank, isnt that just the same?

Comment: I am new to VB.Net...In VBA I used offset method, But don't Know how to Use loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto Fill till data ends in column B VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463010/auto-fill-till-data-ends-in-column-b-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your worksheet variable to get the cells and ranges. Also xlUP = -4162 according to the documentation.

```
Dim ws = objworkbook2.Worksheets("Test USD")
ws.Range ("C2") = "USD"
ws.Range("C2").Copy (ws.Range("C3", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(-4162).Offset(0, 1)))
```