# Auto Fill till data ends in column B VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, autofill

I have little problem in VB.net. I have excel file with data in column A Column B. I want to write value as "USD" in column C till the value end in the column B or Column A.

In Excel VBA, I use

```
Range ("C2") = "USD"
Range("C2").Copy Range("C3", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
```

This fills USD till the value end in column B.

Can anyone help me how to get this in VB.Net?

I have tried something like this in VB.net.

```
With objworkbook2
Dim my_variable As String
Dim Worksheets = objworkbook2.Worksheets("Test USD")
my_variable = "USD"
if Worksheets.Cells(2, 1).Value >= 1 Then 'Cell A9 contains Number
Worksheets.Cell(2, 3).Value = my_variable
End if
End With
```

Please help me how to loop this in VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your worksheet variable to get the cells and ranges. Also xlUP = -4162 according to the documentation.

```
Dim ws = objworkbook2.Worksheets("Test USD")
ws.Range ("C2") = "USD"
ws.Range("C2").Copy (ws.Range("C3", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(-4162).Offset(0, 1)))
```